# Issue using Mobbeel Fataar plugin with uploadArchives task

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, fatjar

I'm in the process of trying to create a fat AAR to distribute my Android library. I'm using the [Mobbeel Fataar plugin](https://github.com/Mobbeel/fataar-gradle-plugin) to package all of my dependencies into an AAR for ease of distribution. This works perfectly, and when I run `./gradlew build`, I get an AAR file in `mylibrary/build/outputs/aar/` called `mylibrary-release.aar` and it includes all of my dependencies in its `libs` directory. The issue arises when I attempt to distribute the AAR.

In order to distribute, I found [this tutorial](https://zserge.com/blog/gradle-maven-publish.html) to take me through it, which I'm using virtually unchanged. Here's that code (in my `build.gradle`):

```
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'signing'

def isReleaseBuild() {
        return VERSION_NAME.contains("SNAPSHOT") == false
}

def getReleaseRepositoryUrl() {
        return hasProperty('RELEASE_REPOSITORY_URL') ? RELEASE_REPOSITORY_URL
                        : "https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/"
}

def getSnapshotRepositoryUrl() {
        return hasProperty('SNAPSHOT_REPOSITORY_URL') ? SNAPSHOT_REPOSITORY_URL
                        : "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
}

def getRepositoryUsername() {
        return hasProperty('NEXUS_USERNAME') ? NEXUS_USERNAME : ""
}

def getRepositoryPassword() {
        return hasProperty('NEXUS_PASSWORD') ? NEXUS_PASSWORD : ""
}

afterEvaluate { project ->
        uploadArchives {
                repositories {
                        mavenDeployer {
                                beforeDeployment { MavenDeployment deployment -> signing.signPom(deployment) }

                                pom.groupId = GROUP
                                pom.artifactId = POM_ARTIFACT_ID
                                pom.version = VERSION_NAME

                                repository(url: getReleaseRepositoryUrl()) {
                                        authentication(userName: getRepositoryUsername(), password: getRepositoryPassword())
                                }
                                snapshotRepository(url: getSnapshotRepositoryUrl()) {
                                        authentication(userName: getRepositoryUsername(), password: getRepositoryPassword())
                                }

                                pom.project {
                                        name POM_NAME
                                        packaging POM_PACKAGING
                                        description POM_DESCRIPTION
                                        url POM_URL

                                        scm {
                                                url POM_SCM_URL
                                                connection POM_SCM_CONNECTION
                                                developerConnection POM_SCM_DEV_CONNECTION
                                        }

                                        licenses {
                                                license {
                                                        name POM_LICENCE_NAME
                                                        url POM_LICENCE_URL
                                                        distribution POM_LICENCE_DIST
                                                }
                                        }

                                        developers {
                                                developer {
                                                        id POM_DEVELOPER_ID
                                                        name POM_DEVELOPER_NAME
                                                }
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                }
        }

        signing {
                required { isReleaseBuild() && gradle.taskGraph.hasTask("uploadArchives") }
                sign configurations.archives
        }

        task androidSourcesJar(type: Jar) {
                classifier = 'sources'
                from android.sourceSets.main.java.sourceFiles
        }

        artifacts {
                archives androidSourcesJar
        }
}
```

The issue is that, when I run `./gradlew :mylibrary:uploadArchives`, it creates a `mylibrary-1.0.aar` file in `mylibrary/build/outputs/aar/` and uploads that file. The problem is that it doesn't have my dependencies bundled in.

I'd like to somehow create `mylibrary-1.0.aar` with all of my dependencies bundled, and then have that be uploaded. Unfortunately I don't have a completely clear understanding of how the upload code I'm using works. Does anyone know how I can do what I want?